# Getting parent repository within service instead of the child I am calling Symfony2.8

Tags: php, symfony

I've looked around for a solution but I seem to have ticked all the boxes with regards to what has already been posted for this issue, My services.yml has been looked over repeatedly and everything seems to be registered correctly. The issue i'm having is that in one of my services, i need to get access to a specific repository but my debugger tells me that its getting the parent of the one I'm looking for instead. Ill paste the code from my service below, maybe someone can see something i've missed. Hope someone can help me because my eyes are square from trying to find the issue.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Repository\DeviceSettingsRepository;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class DeviceSettingsService {

    /** @var  DeviceSettingsRepository */
    protected $deviceSettingsRepository;

    /**
     * DeviceSettingsService constructor.
     * @param $deviceSettingsRepository
     */
    public function __construct($deviceSettingsRepository) {

        $this->deviceSettingsRepository = $deviceSettingsRepository;
    }

    public function updateGpsModeByDeviceId($deviceId, $mode) {

        $this->deviceSettingsRepository->updateGpsModeByDeviceId($deviceId, $mode);
    }
}


parameters:
#    parameter_name: value
    deviceSettingsRepository.factory_argument : 'AppBundle:Mongo\EmbDocument\DeviceSettings'

services:
  deviceSettingsRepository:
           class: AppBundle\Repository\DeviceSettingsRepository
           factory_service: doctrine_mongodb
           factory_method:  getRepository
           arguments:
           - %deviceSettingsRepository.factory_argument%

  deviceSettingsService:
            class: AppBundle\Service\DeviceSettingsService
            arguments: ['@deviceSettingsRepository']
```

Comment: What is "a hold of a specific repository"?

Comment: Not much to do on.  Is device setting repository a Doctrine repository?  If so and by parent do you mean the default Doctrine repository is being given?  Once again, if so, then check your mappings between the device setting entity and the repository.

Comment: How and where is your DeviceSettingsService configured? Please add services.yml

Comment: "A hold" - my bad its an Irishism for getting something - Will add the services.yml now

Comment: According to your code, i would expect getting the AppBundle:Mongo\EmbDocument\DeviceSettings Repository ... which one are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting DocumentRepository for some reason, cant seem to figure out why

Comment: Think i've been stupid actually, the document is embedded and i've just realised you cant use a repositoryClass for embedded documents

Comment: So your factory returns the wrong repo?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't recognise the repo i was looking for as the object class is embedded in another object, I was doing some looking as I was waiting for an answer and it seems i will have to use the repository for the object my one is embedded with, in order to update data in the db. Thanks for the help all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI The issue i was having was that I was trying to create and use a repository for an embedded document. I've since learned that when you have an embedded document you need to use the repository of the parent document to work with data from the child.